# Unicode data is not saved into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, unicode

I am getting error when I tried to save following data into database.

• Independent measurement and calibration of solar cell performance
under space and ****unique**** conditions (i.e., high intensity/
temperature, monochromatic and indoor lighting conditions, etc.)
• ***Novel*** energy conversion devices such as remote, self-powered
sensors; broadband, monochromatic, or thermal energy sources;
integrated communication/power concepts, etc.

I am getting error because some unwanted text(marked as bold and italic in above text) which we can not insert into database. Database table collation is 'utf8_general_ci' and charset is 'utf'

```
Error ::
*03:20:20,775 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
03:20:20,775 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Incorrect string value: '\xF4\x80\x81\xACun...' for column 'VALUE' at row 1
03:20:20,784 ERROR [com.platform.ejb.OpportunityServicesBean] could not insert: [com.platform.valueobject.OpportunityExtension]: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.platform.valueobject.OpportunityExtension]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64) [:3.6.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345) [:3.6.6.Final]*
```

If I will remove that unwanted text then data is saved into database.

Can anybody help me to come out?

Comment: It is basically due to your column data type. set it to unicode in mySQL. SQL Server has nVARCHAR() for unicode character, I dont know about mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as VARCHAR(N) in MySQL but you 
should specify some proper character set and collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-column.html

[image: Example MySQL]